# Multi select dropdownlist in bootstrap not displaying dropdown menus

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to integrate a multiselect dropdown list in my web page. But the list does not show the dropdown menu when click.The dropdown displays its menu  if i remove bootstrap.min.css from head tag, but the menus not aligned well.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Money Withdrawal</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap- 
   select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"  
crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
        <label class="text-white mb-3 lead">Where do you live?</label>
        <!-- Multiselect dropdown -->
        <select multiple="" class="selectpicker" id="exchange_p" tabindex="-98">
                            <option>BSE</option>
                            <option>NSE</option>
                            <option>NCDEX</option>
                            <option>MCX</option>
                            <option>NSDL</option>
                            <option>ICEX</option>
                        </select>           
        </div>
    </div>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap- select.min.js"> 
       </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Please describe what you have done to debug the problem, somebody will probably respond with additional suggestions for ways to debug that might help you spot the problem.  For example, have you run this page in the browser Developer tool (F12 in most browsers)? If so, what did you look at, what were you expecting it to be and what was it actually?

Comment: there is a space in the `<script>` tag... `bootstrap- select.min.js` should be `bootstrap-select.min.js`... also remove `text-white` class to see something work... not sure what you're looking for though